# How to copy the target file vs the symlink

Tags: symlink

I have files with symlinks as shown below :

link_AB91 -> file_12857.xml
link_XY99 -> file_102856.xml
link_EF02 -> file_96843.xml

In my script I reference the link not the actual target file. 
However, when I perform the copy I want the actual file copied over.
I am looking for an option and/or command which will allow me to achieve this.

Example :

```
cp "some_option_here" link_AB91 .
```

This should copy file **file_12857.xml** not the link **link_AB91**
I have tried options -L and -H but they do not help
Note that I do not want the -d or -P option either.

Update : If not option exists, then I will use readlink command but I am hoping there is a quicker way of performing this task

Comment: What do you mean those option "*do not help*"?

Comment: "do not help" as in "do not help solve my problem"

Comment: The `-L` switch should copy the target file. Could you give details of your `cp` invocation and the actual results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `readlink /path/to/link`  to get the real file

```
cp `readlink /path/to/my/link` /foo/destination
```

equals

```
cp $(readlink /path/to/my/link) /foo/destination
```

Comment: What is wrong with that answer?

Comment: I agree. Someone is hellbent on downvoting ! If I dont get a better answer, I will accept this one. Plus 1 btw.

Comment: Downvote is actual. There would better to use `realpath` instead of `readlink` because it provide fullpath to target. If symlink is relative command from your answer will fail.

Comment: @imbearr You should write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

A minor adjustment to [@ansi_lumen's](https://serverfault.com/a/766599/791981) answer:

```
cp `readlink -e /path/to/my/link` /foo/destination
```

This makes a difference for relative links. It makes sure that `cp` gets an absolute path to the file instead of a relative path.

Comment: cp: invalid option -- 'e' - which CP are you referencing?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It outputs the whole path that "cp" requires. If for instance link points to a relative path the "-e" will make readlink output the absolute path.

@djdomi You forgot the `` operators. The -e is for readlink.